# cannot wget wordpress.org

Tags: wget

I am not able to wget wordpress.org from server 63.143.51.2.  I am able to wget other sites like google.com

Error I am getting is as follows :

```
[~]# wget wordpress.org
--2013-04-12 01:42:17-- http://wordpress.org/
Resolving wordpress.org... 72.233.56.139
Connecting to wordpress.org|72.233.56.139|:80...
```

Can anyone provide me steps to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: That's not an error. That's information about what wget is doing. What else happens?

Comment: I am able to ping/tracert the site but only wget is having issue. More likely the issue is with dns of my server or blockage at wordpress.org. Any more suggestions? Could it be server cache?

Comment: what does "having issue" mean? What exactly is happening?

Comment: I am not getting result for wget wordpress.org OR wget wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz               I am having issue with only this site.  Other sites like "wget google.com" are working fine.

Comment: The output gets stuck ~]# wget wordpress.org
--2013-04-12 01:42:17-- http://wordpress.org/
Resolving wordpress.org... 72.233.56.139
Connecting to wordpress.org|72.233.56.139|:80...

Comment: Are there any firewall rules in place on this server? What's the output of `iptables -nL` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloading Wordpress latest release than try below

```
  wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
```

Comment: I am able to ping/tracert the site but only wget is having issue.  More likely the issue is with dns of my server or blockage at wordpress.org.  Any more suggestions?

Comment: What you want to download from wordpress.org ?

Comment: My server hosts wordpress sites and it is important to have connection with wordpress.org using wget command.  I am looking for a more detailed answer like this url http://serverfault.com/questions/213733/dns-issue-on-fedora-12-wget-wordpress-org-fails-where-wget-www-google-com-works?rq=1